# Doing left join/inner join in many-to-many relations with Eloquent In Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, inner-join, eloquent

Is there any way to do inner join using Eloquent in Laravel 4?
Because I don't wanna show Courses without users in it.

Actually I have this.

Controller:

```
$courses = Course::all();
foreach($courses as $course){
  $course->users;
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <h3>{{ $course->course}} :</h3>
    @foreach($course->users as $user)
        <p> {{$user->username}} </p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Class User:

```
public function courses(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('Course','course_user','id_usuario');
}
```

Class Course:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('User','course_user','course_id','id_usuario');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the method [Has();](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) appears to be like *inner join*
So in the controller i do:

```
$courses = Course::has('users')->get();
```

..and that's it :)

Link:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do, fill in your inner join.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Course','course_user','id_usuario')
             ->join('students', 'student_user.user_id', '=', 'students.id')
             ->get();
```

Check out the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins for more info!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried it and Throw me an error, but reading the documentation I figured out that has('users') is like inner-join.